# $("element").remove(); in iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's an example  i m trying to run to delete a div element with class "location_description" in iframe but it doesnt work. Any solution?

**HTML**

```
<div id="kk">
    <iframe id = "weatherFrame" src="https://www.meteoblue.com/el/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82/widget/daily?geoloc=detect&days=4&tempunit=CELSIUS&windunit=KILOMETER_PER_HOUR&coloured=coloured&pictoicon=1&maxtemperature=1&mintemperature=1&layout=light"  frameborder="0" scrolling="NO" allowtransparency="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups" class = "weatherFrame" style = "width: 60%;height: 100%;"></iframe>
    <div> 
        <a href="https://www.meteoblue.com/el/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82/%CF%80%CF%81%CF%8C%CE%B3%CE%BD%CF%89%CF%83%CE%B7/%CE%B5%CE%B2%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%AC%CE%B4%CE%B1?utm_source=weather_widget&utm_medium=linkus&utm_content=daily&utm_campaign=Weather%2BWidget" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**jQuery (end of `<body>`)**

```
$('#weatherFrame').load(function(){
    alert("in");
    $("location_description").remove();
});
```

Comment: Is the iframe content and the main page on the same domain?

Comment: where is`location_description` ?

Answer (score 3):

If the domain of the iframe is not the same as the domain of the parent page, you will not be able to manipulate its content due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

If they're different domains but you have control over its content (that is, you can add code to it), you can use [Postmessaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to do what you are trying to do. Simply add a listener within the iframe's content which tells it when to fire off this change.

From looking at the domain however I imagine this is not your page so there isn't much you can do

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery if you want to remove something by it's class then this will be your statement to do that :

```
$(".location_description").remove();
```

And in an iframe, you cannot do such manipulation.
You can so some thing as below

```js
     iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('Hello ');
```